# grunt task to determine files needed by web app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, gruntjs, yeoman, minify

i'am a newbie and started to build a webapp with yeomans webapp generator and a static html 5 template. The template is able to use over 40 plugins.

The template directoy structure is like:

```
    index.html    
      --assets
        --css
        --js
        --img
      --plugins
          --bootstrap
            --cs
            --fonts
            --js
          ...
          ...
```

My project only uses a quite little part of it.

1. Is it possible to determine which files are used(referenced) within the project, 
   and copy them automatically with a grunt task to the .tmp and .dist folder?
   Currently i used httrack to find that out. But there must be a other way.
   (a special grunt task or perhaps a plugin for webstorm ? )
2. For minifying the output i use the default task with

    'clean', 'jshint', 'copy', 'usemin', 'concat','cssmin', 'uglify'

   which means: 
   'useminPrepare', // Looks for those  in your HTML 
   'concat',        // Task used to concatenate your JS and CSS 
   'cssmin',        // Minifies your CSS files 
   'uglify',        // Task used to minify your JS 
   'copy',          // Copies files from .tmp/ and src/ into dist/ 
   'usemin'         // Updates the references in your HTML with the new files 

   For the concat task i use this code to make sure all needed files are included:

   `concat: {
           css: {
               src: ['src/**/*.css'],
               dest: 'dist/assets/css/main.min.css'
           },
           js: {
               src: ['src/**/*.js'],
               dest: 'dist/assets/js/main.min.js'
           }`

   The resulting files are quite big. Remember the bunch of plugins. 

   What must i do to ensure the resulting files (js/css) contain only the needed parts ?
     As far as i can seen uglify,cssmin etc. doesn't strip the files. Must i include here grunt-uncss or something like that ? The same goes for the html file. After minifing some parts are not working as expected..

   (The best would be a generator where i just put in the complete webpage in the src folder, and the grunt build task produce out of the box an optimized dist folder, only with the need files.)
   Hopefully you outhere can help me with some good advises for my both problems.
   Thx.